# Why does the Apache Beam Source Code Build Fails?

Tags: gradle, build, apache-beam

I am trying to build the Apache Beam release 2.15.0 source code with Gradle.
Following [the repo](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/release-2.15.0), I execute the following command in the source folder.

`$ sudo ./gradlew build --warning-mode=all --stacktrace`

However, the build process terminates on the task `:runners:google-cloud-dataflow-java:test` as you can see in [this picture](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4960/hfsWRX.png).

Some more information about the failure of the test

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (exception with message a string containing "Cannot create output file at" and an instance of java.lang.RuntimeException)
>       at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:285)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$100(ExpectedException.java:115)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:271)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:349)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:314)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:312)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:396)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

My Gradle version is 5.2.1 and I'm using OpenJDK 1.8.0_222.

Can you please help me to identify the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the error report, the path of which starts from "file:///home/batuhan/.../test/index.html" (see your error image)?

Comment: Please see the added test failure information.

Comment: I can guess that it requires you to have an access for Google Cloud to run some tests on Dataflow. If you don't want to run the tests then just add "-x test" to your gradle command.